# Cannot shut down/restart without using the power button please help

Tags: shutdown

I have Lenevo C260 Desktop.. it had windows 8.1 I deleted it and installed the latest version of Ubuntu..,
everything works fine but when i have to shut down  my computer it will kill all the running process but the machine doesn’t shut down   the fan and led indicators remain on i have to press and hold of the power button to shut down manually
i tried this

```
sudo -i (to get a root shell, sudo gedit is not recommended)
gedit /etc/default/grub
Find the line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
Change this to: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
Save the file and close the file.
Finally, in terminal: update-grub
exit (to end the root shell)
```

and even  tried `sudo shutdown -h now` in terminal but that doesn’t turn off the machine although it does turn off system but not machine..,  i know many have asked this questions but  i couldn’t get any solution from most of it .., please Give solution..!!

Answer (score 0):

`man shutdown` would have been of use to you.

`sudo shutdown -P now` will power down the system now.

the -h switch only halts the system and doesn't power it down.